# Assignment of a parenthesized expression

Tags: c, expression

Consider the following snippet:

```
int a, b, c;
a = (b = 3, c = 4, 5, 6);
```

It turns out that, after those lines are executed, b has the value 3, c has the value 4. Nothing unexpected so far. But a has value 6. Why is that?

Also, does this have an useful use?

Comment: See [What does the comma operator `,` do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/52550/1708801)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `,` operator discards all the operands to the left, and since `6` is the rightmost operand, it's the only one which is not discarded.

This is from **§ 6.5.17** n1570 draft

> 2. The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>      sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
>      operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.
> 3. EXAMPLE As indicated by the syntax, the comma operator (as described in this subclause) cannot
>      appear in contexts where a comma is used to separate items in a list (such as arguments to functions or lists
>      of initializers). On the other hand, it can be used within a parenthesized expression or within the second
>      expression of a conditional operator in such contexts. In the function call
>
>    ```
>    f(a, (t=3, t+2), c)
>    ```
>
>    the function has three arguments, the second of which has the value 5.

You can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Comment: Wikipedia has good examples on `,` operator. You can post them to further extend this answer.

Comment: I added the one from the draft.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a separator (i.e. ',') in an assignment statement, it assigns a value that is in the last. For example

    int i = (2,3);
    // i = 3;
variable i get the value of 3 not 2.